# Using gitk on msysgit

Tags: git, msysgit, gitk

I'm trying to use the gitk on mysysgit.  I'm not using Cygwin or MinGW to run mysysgit, just a straight up DOS command prompt on Windows.

The gitk file is in the bin/ folder, but it's not an executable, so when I type `gitk` I get:

> 'gitk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Comment: gitk is a TCL application so it needs to be run with wish.exe found in the /bin folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `gitk.cmd` from the `cmd/` folder

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed `Git for windows` and you're running `cmder` on windows and unable to launch `gitk`, then:

- Press superkey, search System Environmental Varibales. You shall see `Edit system environmental variables` there.
- Edit the PATH (the caps one on top)
- Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd` (or whatever the right path be) at the end, and terminate the line with a semicolon
- relaunch cmder
- instead of `gitk`, write now `gitk.cmd`

Done.

**Note:** The above instruction may stand valid for command line tools other than `mingw` or `cygwin` or `bash` like shells

Comment: or install Git for Windows, add `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` and use `gtik` as the command

Comment: The question was pertinent to non-cygwin & non-mingw users. `gitk` din't work for me while using `cmder`.